# how to set UIView background programmatically

Tags: iphone

in the interface builder,i can find the background tag,and select the color and the opacity.

if I create the UIView programmatically,if I want to change color,I can set the backgroundColor property

the question is if I want to change the opactiy,What is the property should I change?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

Use the view's `alpha` property, or, if you don't want the view's content to have the same opacity change applied to it, change the alpha component of the background color (as created with `+colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha:`, `+colorWithHue:saturation:brightness:alpha:`, or `+colorWithWhite:alpha:`) to something other than 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use

```
self.alpha = someFloat;
```

in your view class.

If you want to change it from viewcontroller, use

```
self.view.alpha = someFloat;
```